# Calculate and plot multiple densities?

Tags: r, plot

I have a matrix with multiple columns and I'd like do calculate the density of each column, and then plot those densities in one single R base plot. Also It would be easier if the plot had a corrected scale automatically.

```
m <- matrix(rnorm(10), 5, 10))
```

Comment: This can be done easily in ggplot2, would you like a solution with these package?

Comment: I have eopened the question. The purported duplicated was about ggplot2 but this question specifically asks for a base plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a list of densities `d`, compute the `xlim` and `ylim` values and use those to create an empty plot.  Finally draw each of the densities on that plot and optionally draw a legend. As requested, this uses only base R.

```
set.seed(123)
m <- matrix(rnorm(50), 5, 10) # test data

d <- apply(m, 2, density)

xlim <- range(sapply(d, "[[", "x"))
ylim <- range(sapply(d, "[[", "y"))
plot(NA, xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim, ylab = "density")

nc <- ncol(m)
cols <- rainbow(nc)
for(i in 1:nc) lines(d[[i]], col = cols[i])

legend("topright", legend = 1:nc, lty = 1, col = cols, cex = 0.7)
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

It can also be done with `ggplot2`:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
#Data
set.seed(123)
m <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(50), 5, 10))
#Melt
meltdata <- melt(m)
#Plot 1
ggplot(meltdata,aes(value,color=variable))+
  geom_density()+ggtitle('Plot 1')
#Plot 2
ggplot(meltdata,aes(value,fill=variable))+
  geom_density(alpha=0.6)+ggtitle('Plot 2')
```

[image]

[image]